# How to test Wake Lock

Tags: android, wakelock, powermanager

I'm working on a fairly complex application and I am using alarms to wake the device when needed and to acquire a wake lock until the task is over. This happens in different places in code. I'm fairly certain my logic is correct but it's very hard to properly test it.

ADB seems to hold a wake lock of it's own.

How can I test to see if all my wake locks (System wide) are released and the device is actually asleep?

Comment: "... a fairly complex application..." is usually a trigger for myself and my own code to write a smallest-possible app to test this particular part of my work within the system and then apply what I learn within the intended application...

Comment: I agree, but the issue here isn't applying what I've learned. The issue is testing what I've applied. I believe @Murillo Henrique's answer is probably the best way to test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the same Alarm to schedule some task after 20 minutes (this should be enough for any device enter on "sleep state"), this could be something like play a song or something that could notify you. Schedule the alarm without the wake lock, your task should fail.

Remember to unplug your device from ADB.

Comment: I think that's a reasonable solution. The app talks to a server every X number of minutes. If I change the alarm type to not wake then it should fail to connect to the server at the exact correct time.

Comment: Just remember that if your X minutes is short, your app can still be able to connect to your server (because the device didn't have enough time to sleep, so the alarm didn't stopped). Good luck with your app :)